# code treeNode selected for nested RadTreeView?

Tags: c#, treenode

I have a 3 level deep RadTreeView that only works on the first Item.
Whenever I select the second or third Item down (or it's child) I get a PostBack that then sets the top Item back to selected.

How should this be coded differently?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //.... code
    treeManageUsers.DataTextField = "CompanyName";
    treeManageUsers.DataFieldID = "CompanyID";
    treeManageUsers.DataValueField = "CompanyID";
    treeManageUsers.DataSource = dsLocations;
    treeManageUsers.DataBind();

    RadTreeNode treeNode = treeManageUsers.Nodes[0];
    treeNode.Selected = true;

    strCompanyID = treeNode.Value.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Where is treeManageUsers set?  Because the code you posted does indeed always select the same node:  `RadTreeNode treeNode = treeManageUsers.Nodes[0];`

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore it gets changed in _NodeClick which unfortuantely does a postback unless that postback could be stopped?